# How to change “message” value in index

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, cdn, elk

In logstash pipeline or indexpattern how to change the following part of CDN log in "message" field to seperate or extract some data then aggrigate them.

```
<40> 2022-01-17T08:31:22Z logserver-5 testcdn[1]: {"method":"GET","scheme":"https","domain":"www.123.com","uri":"/product/10809350","ip":"66.249.65.174","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)","country":"US","asn":15169,"content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","status":200,"server_port":443,"bytes_sent":1892,"bytes_received":1371,"upstream_time":0.804,"cache":"MISS","request_id":"b017d78db4652036250148216b0a290c"}
```

expected change:

```
{"method":"GET","scheme":"https","domain":"www.123.com","uri":"/product/10809350","ip":"66.249.65.174","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)","country":"US","asn":15169,"content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","status":200,"server_port":443,"bytes_sent":1892,"bytes_received":1371,"upstream_time":0.804,"cache":"MISS","request_id":"b017d78db4652036250148216b0a290c"}
```

Bacause this part "**<40> 2022-01-17T08:31:22Z logserver-5 testcdn[1]:**" is not parsed in jason and I can't create visual dashboard based on some fileds such as country, asn, etc...

The original log that indexed by logstash is:

```html
{
  "_index": "logstash-2022.01.17-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Qx8pZ34BhloLEkDviGxe",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "message": "<40> 2022-01-17T08:31:22Z logserver-5 testcdn[1]: {\"method\":\"GET\",\"scheme\":\"https\",\"domain\":\"www.123.com\",\"uri\":\"/product/10809350\",\"ip\":\"66.249.65.174\",\"ua\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\",\"country\":\"US\",\"asn\":15169,\"content_type\":\"text/html; charset=utf-8\",\"status\":200,\"server_port\":443,\"bytes_sent\":1892,\"bytes_received\":1371,\"upstream_time\":0.804,\"cache\":\"MISS\",\"request_id\":\"b017d78db4652036250148216b0a290c\"}",
    "port": 39278,
    "@timestamp": "2022-01-17T08:31:22.100Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "93.115.150.121"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-01-17T08:31:22.100Z"
    ],
    "port": [
      39278
    ],
    "@version": [
      "1"
    ],
    "host": [
      "93.115.150.121"
    ],
    "message": [
      "<40> 2022-01-17T08:31:22Z logserver-5 testcdn[1]: {\"method\":\"GET\",\"scheme\":\"https\",\"domain\":\"www.123.com\",\"uri\":\"/product/10809350\",\"ip\":\"66.249.65.174\",\"ua\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\",\"country\":\"US\",\"asn\":15169,\"content_type\":\"text/html; charset=utf-8\",\"status\":200,\"server_port\":443,\"bytes_sent\":1892,\"bytes_received\":1371,\"upstream_time\":0.804,\"cache\":\"MISS\",\"request_id\":\"b017d78db4652036250148216b0a290c\"}"
    ],
    "host.keyword": [
      "93.115.150.121"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these configurations to filter section of you logstash config:

```
#To parse the message field
grok {
    match => { "message" => "<%{NONNEGINT:syslog_pri}>\s+%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp}\s+%{DATA:sys_host}\s+%{NOTSPACE:sys_module}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"}
}
#To replace message field with syslog_message
mutate {
    replace => [ "message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
}
```

Once the message field is replaced by syslog_message, You can add the json filter below to parse the json to separate fields as well..

```
json {
    source => "syslog_message"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, This is very useful, I got an idea from your suggestion for this specific scenario:
The following edited logstash.conf solves this problem :

```js
input {
  tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json
  }
}

filter {
   grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:Junk}: %{GREEDYDATA:request}"}
        }
   json { source => "request" }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    ecs_compatibility => disabled
    index => "logs-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

But my main concern is about editing config files, I'd prefer make any changes in kibana web ui rather than changing logstash.conf, because we use elk for diffrent scenarios in the organization and such changes make an elk server proper for just a special purpose not for multi purposes.
How to get such result without changing logstash config files?

Comment: I understand your concern here. But this is the flow of log processing in standard Elastic-stack.
Another way to parse the logs into separate fields using kibana as you asked is to use runtime field. This can be helpful when you dont have access to logstash server or you don't wanna alter the logstash configurations.

This has its own pros and cons, as the runtime field gets generated while querying from kibana and doesn't actually get stored anywhere.

you can read about it more here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/runtime.html